# How to prevent irb or pry from starting thread automatically

Tags: ruby, multithreading, irb, pry

When I create a new thread in pry or irb, it is immediately started.

```
[1] pry(main)> th = Thread.new {puts "hi"}
hi
=> #<Thread:0x00007ff09b8e8c10@(pry):1 dead>
[2] pry(main)> th.join
=> #<Thread:0x00007ff09b8e8c10@(pry):1 dead>
```

...

```
irb(main):001:0> th = Thread.new {puts 'hi'}
=> #<Thread:0x00007fe2cc91e860@(irb):1 run>
hi
irb(main):002:0> th.join
=> #<Thread:0x00007fe2cc91e860@(irb):1 dead>
```

Is there any way to prevent this?
Not sure how this behavior could be useful; I'd like it to behave like it would if I ran it in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it in a file, they DO start automatically.

You can immediately pause a thread by issuing a Stop in the beginning of the block.

```
th = Thread.new { Thread.stop; puts 'hi' }
# not running yet
th.run
# now will print 'hi'
th.join
```

Comment: Okay, I must have misunderstood the documentation then.. So, `th.join` is simply blocking the main thread until the already running thread `th` finishes?

Comment: `th = Thread.new { sleep 5; puts 'BEFORE' }; th.join; puts "AFTER"`
Looks like it